Blazor @page "/search" is not found
I'm just starting to use Blazor. I'm using Net 8 In Visual Studio 2022
This is my App.razor file
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

The directory structure is the default
--Features
        -->Home
                --> HomePage.razor
                --> TestPage.razor

My HomePage is the main page.
@page "/"

My TestPage.razor has this
    @page "/Test"
    <PageTitle>TEST</PageTitle>
    <h3>TEST results</h3>

When I run the App. its open in HomePage it the URL
https://localhost:7258/

But when I want to redirect to TestPage I change the URL to
 https://localhost:7258/Test

But it appears the message
Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

I checked .csproj file as says here
Adding
 <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Features\Home\" />
  </ItemGroup>

But nothing has changed..
What I am missing?
Thanks

Are you using Visual Studio?

Hi, YES, Visual studio 2022, thanks

It was my fault, I had a compilation error due to the use of SASS that I will discuss in another post. The Page was not recognized.
Thanks
